# How to keep main window from closing

Tags: python, exception, pyqt5

I've written a code that opens a window with textarea. We can clear this textarea, save this textarea or open a different textareas.

Problem I'm facing is that when I try to close or save a textarea without any action on dialog, the main window is shutting down. I don't want it to shutdown. How can I solve that?

When I close the save window, I get this error:

> Process finished with exit code 1073741845

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton,QApplication,QVBoxLayout,QWidget,QLabel,QTextEdit,QHBoxLayout,QFileDialog


class NotePad(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.textname = QTextEdit()

        self.clear = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.open = QPushButton("Open")
        self.save = QPushButton("Save")

        h_box = QHBoxLayout()

        h_box.addWidget(self.clear)
        h_box.addWidget(self.open)
        h_box.addWidget(self.save)

        v_box = QVBoxLayout()

        v_box.addWidget(self.textname)

        v_box.addLayout(h_box)

        self.setLayout(v_box)

        self.clear.clicked.connect(self.clean)
        self.open.clicked.connect(self.isopen)
        self.save.clicked.connect(self.saved)
        self.show()


    def clean(self):
        self.textname.clear()

    def isopen(self):
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open",os.getenv("HOME"))

        with open(file_name[0],"r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            self.textname.setText(file.read())

    def saved(self):

        file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save",os.getenv("HOME"))

        with open(file_name[0],"w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(self.textname.toPlainText())



app = QApplication(sys.argv)

pencere = NotePad()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are closing the "file-open" or "file-save" popups, without any valid action, you are getting exceptions in respective functions.

So you should try to handle those exceptions gracefully. It completely depends on you as to how you want to handle those, but for catching exceptions, you have to use 'try', 'except', 'finally' keywords in Python. Like this:

```
def isopen(self):
    file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Open",os.getenv("HOME"))
    try:
        with open(file_name[0],"r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            self.textname.setText(file.read())
    except:
        pass  # Add code for what you want to do here


def saved(self):
    file_name = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save",os.getenv("HOME"))
    try:
        with open(file_name[0],"w",encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file.write(self.textname.toPlainText())
    except:
        pass  # Add code for what you want to do here
```